# I have created a google PO with Google Sheets, but would like to limit it to one user at a time. Is there way to go this, maybe with a script?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have created a PO order form for my interal team and want them to be able to access it one at a time to avoid any ordering issues.

I thought to protect the worksheet with a password but that doesn't seem like the best option.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65832680/gas-script-is-it-possible-to-prevent-simultaneous-user) help in any way?